# reactjs update setState from map object data

Tags: reactjs

I want to update my `setValidDate` state with `date` that is coming from the `item`, but when I set the value right after the data got mapped I got an error says `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop`.
Is there any way to update the new value? And why it's error?

```
const [validDate, setValidDate] = useState("");

return(
  ...
 {items.map((item) => {
 const { id, name, date, image, desc } = item;
 setValidDate(date); //this one cause error
 return (
  ...
        )
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why are you calling `setValidDate` in a loop? When you do that, it triggers a rerender of the component which then causes infinite rerenders

Comment: why you want update validDate when loop your items?

Comment: You cannot update the state from the render itself. Updating a state re-triggers a render therefore causing an infinite loop

Comment: basically, I want to set all the value of ```date``` into ```validDate``` so later on I can compare it with the user input, if it's matched then it does something

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you are looking for:**

```
const [validDate, setValidDate] = useState("");

updateDate(date){
  setValidDate(date) 
}

return(
  ...
 {items.map((item) => {
 const { id, name, date, image, desc } = item;
 return (
  <input onChange={()=> updateDate(date)}>
        )
)
```

Comment: this will return ```<input/>``` as many as ```item.length```